# Calculating exponential of a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to calculate the exponential of a 200x200 matrix (expm(B)) and get the following problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
exp_matrix2 = expm(B)
```

> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py", line
>   261, in expm
>       return scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(A)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py",
>   line 582, in expm
>       return _expm(A, use_exact_onenorm='auto')
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py",
>   line 618, in _expm
>       eta_1 = max(h.d4_loose, h.d6_loose)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py",
>   line 457, in d4_loose
>       structure=self.structure)**(1/4.)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py",
>   line 301, in _onenormest_matrix_power
>       MatrixPowerOperator(A, p, structure=structure))
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_onenormest.py",
>   line 95, in onenormest
>       est, v, w, nmults, nresamples = _onenormest_core(A, A.H, t, itmax)
>
> File "/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/_onenormest.py",
>   line 424, in _onenormest_core
>       Z = np.asarray(AT_linear_operator.matmat(S))
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py",
>   line 326, in matmat
>       Y = self._matmat(X)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py",
>   line 468, in _matmat
>       return super(_CustomLinearOperator, self)._matmat(X)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py",
>   line 174, in _matmat
>       return np.hstack([self.matvec(col.reshape(-1,1)) for col in X.T])
>
> File
>   "/home/dk2518/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py",
>   line 219, in matvec
>       y = self._matvec(x)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py",
>   line 471, in _matvec
>       return self.__matvec_impl(x)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py",
>   line 266, in rmatvec
>       y = self._rmatvec(x)
>
> File ".../python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py",
>   line 203, in _rmatvec
>       x = A_T.dot(x)
>
> ValueError: shapes (207,207) and (1,207) not aligned: 207 (dim 1) != 1
>   (dim 0)

Comment: Not sure how your matrix is created, but check this [scipy GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7404) to see if this helps by using `np.block`

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in @TomNash's link, a large `np.matrix` is the problem.

`ndarray` and `sparse` matrix work fine:

```
In [309]: slg.expm(np.ones((200,200)));                                         
In [310]: slg.expm(sparse.csc_matrix(np.ones((200,200))));                      
In [311]: slg.expm(np.matrix(np.ones((200,200))));  
ValueError: shapes (200,200) and (1,200) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Not every `np.matrix` gives problems:

```
In [313]: slg.expm(np.matrix(np.eye(200)));
```

Turning the `np.matrix` back into `ndarray` works:

```
In [315]: slg.expm(np.matrix(np.ones((200,200))).A);
```

This uses `slg.matfuncs._expm(A, use_exact_onenorm='auto')`

which has an test, early one, for:

```
if use_exact_onenorm == "auto":
    # Hardcode a matrix order threshold for exact vs. estimated one-norms.
    use_exact_onenorm = A.shape[0] < 200
```

That explains, in part, why we get the problem with a (200,200) matrix, but not a (199,199).

This works:

```
slg.matfuncs._expm(M, use_exact_onenorm=True);
```

It fails with `False`.  But from there I get lost in the details of how it sets up `_ExpmPadeHelper` and attempts a  `Pade order 3`.

In short - avoid `np.matrix`, especially if (200,200) or larger.